# OpenVPN IPv6 ping outside and inside network but can't surf web

Tags: centos, networking, iptables, openvpn, ipv6

I have an OpenVPN server configured to use IPv4 and IPv6.

IPv4 it's all OK - I can ping and surf internet.

IPv6 can ping only.

I have a /48 assign to me by Hurricane tunnel broker and configured to assign ipv6 to my test network. From outside I can ping ipv6 assigned to me by vpn and I can ping in ipv6 internet from my client. If I try to surf web in ipv6 such as ipv6.google.com or some ipv6 test web page, they don't recognize ipv6 assigned by vpn but if i run a traceroute6 or ping6 from test pages there is no problem they can ping or trace my ipv6.
to trace my ipv6 i used https://centralops.net/co/Traceroute.aspx

Does anyone have any idea what the cause may be? I tried various parameters and configuration for OpenVPN but nothing has changed.
Could it be an Iptables rules problem? Any suggestion?

iptables6:

ip6tables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -s my:ipv6:he:vpn:subnet::/112 -o ens192 -j MASQUERADE
ip6tables -I INPUT 1 -i tun0 -j ACCEPT ip6tables -I FORWARD 1 -i ens192 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -I FORWARD 1 -i tun0 -o ens192 -j ACCEPT.
ip6tables -I INPUT 1 -i ens192 -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT

edit:

i had disable ip6tables, now whatismyipaddress.com can find my ipv6 but I still not surf...

edit 2:

i had install Viscosity client and all is running now... no other change made to my configuration.

Thank you anyway

Comment: Not nearly enough info. Where is it? What is it trying to contact? Does the ISP it is connected to support IPv6? Does it have a routable IPv6 address? What is the routing table? Please don't get into `my car does not start, anyone know why?`

Comment: Typically, a routing level success (`ping` or `traceroute`) with an application level failure (web browsing) means your DNS is failing. Can your machine resolve names to IPv6 addresses? For example, does `ipv6.google.com` resolve correctly?

Comment: Yes I can ping ipv6.google.com.  I think i had miss something in my iptables rules…
This is my iptables6:

ip6tables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -s my:ipv6:he:vpn:subnet::/112 -o ens192 -j MASQUERADE
ip6tables -I INPUT 1 -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -I FORWARD 1 -i ens192 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -I FORWARD 1 -i tun0 -o ens192 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -I INPUT 1 -i ens192 -p udp --dport 1294 -j ACCEPT

Comment: Please don't add information in the comments. Add it to your question (with context so people understand what you're telling us). The comments are only for getting clarifications, and could be deleted at any time.